# Compiling Expression throws cannot be used for return type ArgumentException

Tags: c#, lambda, expression, expression-trees

I am trying to get more familiar with expression trees.

I have created a simple switch expression as follows:

```
var paramExp = Expression.Parameter(typeof(int));
Expression<Func<int>> defaultBodyExp = () => 4;
var switchBodyExp = Expression.Switch(paramExp, defaultBodyExp,
    Expression.SwitchCase(defaultBodyExp, Expression.Constant(1)));
var func = Expression.Lambda<Func<int, int>>(switchBodyExp, paramExp).Compile();
int result = func(6);
```

But this raises the following exception when trying to call `Compile`:

> Expression of type 'System.Func`1[System.Int32]' cannot be used for return type 'System.Int32'

I can get it working by doing the following:

```
var paramExp = Expression.Parameter(typeof(int));
//Expression<Func<int>> defaultBodyExp = () => 4;
var defaultBodyMethodInfo = typeof(Program).GetMethod("DefaultBody");
var switchBodyExp = Expression.Switch(paramExp, Expression.Call(defaultBodyMethodInfo),
    Expression.SwitchCase(Expression.Call(defaultBodyMethodInfo), Expression.Constant(1)));
var func = Expression.Lambda<Func<int, int>>(switchBodyExp, paramExp).Compile();
int result = func(6);

public static int DefaultBody()
{
    return 4;
}
```

But I'm really not sure why my first example doesn't work and I'd love to know how to do that properly so I don't have to declare a method like in my second example. Do I need to be doing some sort of call invoke like in the second example?

I've had a look at some of the other similar answers on SO, but I'm new enough with Expression Trees this that I'm really not sure if they answer my problem or not.

Comment: Change these lines and it runs -  `var func = Expression.Lambda<Func<int, Func<int>>>(switchBodyExp, paramExp).Compile();` and `int result = func(6).Invoke();`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The *lambda expression* `Expression<Func<int>>` can only be used directly in a places that expect `Func<int>` (like `Enumerable.Select`) or  `Expression<Func<int>>` (like `Queryable.Select`, but you need to wrap it inside [`Expression.Quote`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.expressions.expression.quote(v=vs.110).aspx)).

In order to use it in a places which expect `int` like in your case, it needs to be converted to an expression that represents the result of the "execution" of the lambda expression. Let change the original code to

```
Expression<Func<int>> defaultBodyLambda = () => 4;
var defaultBodyExp = ???;
```

and the question is what should `???` be.

One possible (and the general) solution is to use the [`Expression.Invoke`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb355170(v=vs.110).aspx) method:

```
var defaultBodyExp = Expression.Invoke(defaultBodyLambda);
```

Or, since this particular lambda expression has no parameters, we can simply use the [`LambdaExpression.Body`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.expressions.lambdaexpression.body(v=vs.110).aspx) property:

```
var defaultBodyExp = defaultBodyLambda.Body;
```

Comment: Works perfectly thanks, and cheers for taking the time to explain why!